# A slightly canonical way to associate a scheme to a Noetherian spectral space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, schemes

Let $C$ be the category whose objects are Noetherian spectral topological spaces and whose morphisms are homeomorphisms. Let $\mathrm{AffSch}$ be the category of Noetherian affine schemes (morphisms are morphisms of schemes). Let $\mathrm{SpecSpc}$ be the category of Noetherian spectral topological spaces (morphisms are continuous maps).

We have an obvious functor $I:C\rightarrow \mathrm{SpecSpc}$ and the forgetful functor $F:\mathrm{AffSch}\rightarrow \mathrm{SpecSpc}$. Does there exist a functor $G:C\rightarrow \mathrm{AffSch}$ such that $F\circ G=I$?

A slightly less functorial question: is every Noetherian spectral space the underlying space of a Noetherian scheme?

Comment: Hochster addresses much of this without the noetherian assumption in http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-142-00/S0002-9947-1969-0251026-X/

Comment: Meta discussion here:  https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-new-users